# Unexpected token on spread operator in Chrome?

Tags: javascript

I was testing something in my Chrome dev tools with the following code:

```
const one = {a: "a", b: "b"};
const two = { ...one, c: "c" };
VM417:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
```

Why do I get this error on the spread operator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are attempting [Object rest/spread](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread), which has not quite made it into the ES6 specification.  So, spreading into an object isn't supported yet, only spreading into an array.

Object rest/spread is currently a Stage 3 proposal.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out. Also, I found this to be helpful - the process for new features: http://2ality.com/2015/11/tc39-process.html

Answer (score 2):

Now spreading the Object is supported in ES6
`const one = {a: "a", b: "b"};
const two = { ...one, c: "c" };`